# Why does my APK file say app-debug.apk? How do I rename it?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Whenever I try to export my code file it always exports as app-debug.apk. Is there any way to change its name without messing up my code? The reason I am asking is because I recently changed my app name in the wrong spot and the whole program stopped working.

Comment: It says the debug apk because there are two types of apk that we can create debug and release. And you can rename the apk in that apk containing folder.I tried it many times

Comment: Could you tell me how exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because your module name is app and build type is debug. To change the outputFileName place below code in android {} section of your app build.gradle file (it is the format I use for my apps, you can name the way you want taking this as reference)

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all {
            def appName = "YourAppName"
            def date = new Date()
            def formattedDate = date.format('MMM-dd-yyyy')
            outputFileName = appName + formattedDate + "-${variant.versionName}-${variant.versionCode}.apk"
        }
    }
```

Comment: I get the appname part and how to change it, but what about the build type? how do I change this?

Comment: Also, could I still export my file to another computer and still run the code if it is debug instead of release?

Comment: Do I need the date? What would I use that for?

Comment: The build type depends on what type you select while generating the APK. You should check this to understand it better https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants

It doesn't matter if it is a debug or release you can run it on any device. But you cannot upload a debug build to app store.

Comment: Okay, but if I wanted to send the code to my teacher he would be able to run it on an emulator even if it says debug...

Comment: You can just remove that date part. As I mentioned, it is for your reference, you can remove or add depending on what you want the result to be.

Comment: Yes, he can run even if it is a debug build.

Comment: does this go in the build.gradle for the project or the module?

Comment: It goes in to the app module

Answer (score 2):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

def buildType = ""

android {

    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.deep.practicle"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            buildType = "release"
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug{
            buildType = "debug"
        }

    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

}

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->

    variant.outputs.all {
        def appName = buildType
        outputFileName = appName + "-${variant.versionName}.apk"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    // Support
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

}
```

Hi Bro, just variable create in build.gradle.

Answer (score 2):

On the left side of Android Studio, choose Build Variants. This is 3rd tab from bottom. Select "release" instead of "debug". Your release APK will be placed in the release folder. It will not be appended with a "debug".